# GWT 2.1 Editors framework

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I'm looking for some documentation or examples on how to use the [GWT 2.1 Editor framework](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html). Google's documentation is uh, somewhat lacking.

From the limited documentation available, I've been able to glean that editors will (in theory) allow you to more easily bind GUI elements to data models. This will alleviate the very common task of copying data into a TextArea/ListBox/CheckBox, and then replicating the user's changes back to the underlying model (and ultimately the DB).

If it does indeed deliver on this, it will be very welcome. For now, I'm left scratching my head as to how to implement any of it.  Any pointers to documentation or examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: +1 I generally really like the GWT documentation, but the page which "covers" the editor framework is really the negative exception.

Comment: Roo doesn't generate editor code yet, but it does generate a lot of other stuff, including activities and places. I find that its generated code is a pretty useful reference to how to do the basics.

Comment: @Chris Lercher- unfortunately this kind of documentation seems to be the rule rather than the exception for Google. It seems like the bleeding-edge code gets released months ahead of minimal documentation, and I often find that "useful" documentation trails by as much as a year or more.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on the subject: http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-21-editors HTH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been in the same place for a while, trying to figure out how Editors hook up with the RequestFactory stuff.  The DynaTableRF sample in the GWT 2.1.1 release is what finally started making things come together - it's complex, but I think you need a complex app to start seeing the benefits.  The code in each step is wonderfully simple - but there are a lot of steps!

Answer (score 7):

A little while ago, when I was in the same situation (not only did the snippets from the Google documentation not work, but they also left out the most basic glue code to make them work), I attempted to write the **most basic Editors example** project for myself. I learned the editor basics from the DynaTableRf example (which is way too complex to get started with Editors IMO), and put something together.

Let me warn you: It's simple, but it's raw and unpolished, it's just a proof of concept. It's just a zip of my Eclipse project: http://www.mediafire.com/file/nwsohz7ov3cx173/playGwtEditors-02.zip *(note: This is the old version for GWT 2.1)*

**Update**

I just updated the project to use GWT 2.3. The old GWT 2.1 bug which I had mentioned in my project is gone now. Here's the new version: http://www.mediafire.com/file/u1yffwuxi441dip/playGwtEditors-03.zip

Comment: Thanks for posting this - when I am done with RequestFactory and need to start w/ Editors in earnest I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: Thank You! Your playGwtEditors app was what really broke the ice for me concerning adopting Editors into an MVP framework. One thing to note - 2.2 allows re-firing after flush violations but not after persist violation. There is an open ticket for "AutoBean has been frozen error" at this date.

Comment: MediaFire sucks big time (stuck at 0.4 MB). Try to use DropBox or Box.net next time please!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using Editor Framework with Request Factory hope it helps too. 
https://github.com/mgenov/injecting-request-factory