# playEditor app Gwt Validator

Tags: validation, gwt, gwt-editors

I was looking at the playEditor app to learn and the app loads up but the validator does not work after the first time.Do you have an updated version?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean my little (intentionally unpolished) example from this post: [GWT 2.1 Editors framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979116/gwt-2-1-editors-framework/5001622#5001622) - no, I don't have an updated version.

The problem was, that once the validation *passes*, it stops working. I believe, the way the Editor framework is/was meant to be used (at least with GWT 2.1) is that you close the editor Dialog/Panel/..., as soon as the validation is correct. When you want to use it again after that, you'd have to create a new Dialog (where validation works once again).

This is actually one of the main reasons, why I'm currently not using the framework. I often prefer re-usable forms over closing dialogs, so it didn't seem ideal for me.

Note that I haven't made a new attempt for GWT 2.2 - and maybe I didn't try hard enough even for GWT 2.1 - so I would be glad, if someone finds a solution!